# eclipse.ini file not present on Mac

Tags: eclipse, configuration

I am trying to alter my eclipse configuration, but the eclipse.ini file is not present in my eclipse installation directory.

I am on Mac os x with eclipse 4.2.1 Juno.

Did the eclipse.ini file get replaced with the config.ini in eclipse/configuration?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The file should be found at `Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini`

For example: `/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS`

Alternatively it might be found instead at `Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini` (Both possibilities are noted in different parts of the [wiki documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini), and it may be that `/Eclipse/` is used for newer versions.)

Comment: As of Neon - if you use the installer which lets you choose your version of Eclipse AFTER downloading then the default install location is different. For me it was `/Users/username/eclipse/jee-neon/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini`

Comment: This is no longer necessarily correct. My .ini file is in: /Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse

Comment: Since I had to make lombok works with STS4 (SpringToolSuite4) I took the following steps:
1. `cp ~/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.16.18/lombok-1.16.18.jar /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app/Contents/MacOS/lombok.jar`
2. `echo "-javaagent:lombok.jar" >> /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app/Contents/Eclipse/SpringToolSuite4.ini`

Answer (score 74):

Here is how you reach that file.

1. If your eclipse link is in dock. go to the link press the control key and left click and go to option and select show in finder. 
   [image]
2. Once you see the link in finder. go to the link and press the control key and left click and select `Show package Content`.
   [image]
3. go to Contents -> MacOS -> eclipse.ini and open in your favorite text editor.
   [image]

Comment: I am using Android ADT in MacOS.
 That's what I am looking for. Thanks you

Comment: @Ashish show in finder doesn't do anything for me in El Capitan and Eclipse Neon

Answer (score 18):

On mac machine do the following to see eclipse.ini file

1. Right click on eclipse icon as in image.(Note: From which ever folder it was installed)
2. Select Show Package Contents second option from list.
3. Select Contents-->MacOS-->eclipse.ini file

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot, I din't know that "show package contents" command

Answer (score 4):

**On Mac High Sierra**

Go to : **Applications** > **Eclipse** (Right-click on the icon and select "**Show Package Contents**") > **Contents** > **Eclipse**

Answer (score 2):

As of Neon the default install location is not `/Applications` but `/Users/username/eclipse`.

My installation was at:

`/Users/username/eclipse`

The 'app' was at:

`/Users/username/eclipse/jee-neon/Eclipse.app`

And the 'eclipse.ini' file was at:

`/Users/username/eclipse/jee-neon/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini`

Comment: You're right they moved the location to the Eclipse folder.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, in eclipse installation folder, Right click on 'eclipse' (alias or a symbolic link) -> Show Original -> eclipse.ini

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse Mars the location moved on Macs to the Eclipse folder.

```
myComputerName:Eclipse myDriveName$ pwd
/Users/myUser/eclipse/jee-mars2/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse
BYOD-1170:Eclipse ijet-sd$ ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   7 ijet-sd  staff   238 Mar 24 13:54 .
drwxr-xr-x   6 ijet-sd  staff   204 Jan 19  2016 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 ijet-sd  staff    60 Sep  2  2015 .eclipseproduct
drwxr-xr-x  12 ijet-sd  staff   408 Mar 24 13:54 configuration
drwxr-xr-x   2 ijet-sd  staff    68 Jan 19  2016 dropins
-rw-r--r--   1 ijet-sd  staff  1113 Mar  1 12:23 eclipse.ini
drwxr-xr-x   3 ijet-sd  staff   102 Jan 19  2016 readme
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes For ***Eclipse NEON***
it should be

> /Users/username/eclipse/jee-neon/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclips‌​e/eclipse.ini

Answer (score 0):

I was using STS and the file was named differently. It was located at `/Applications/STS.app/Contents/Eclipse/STS.ini`.

Answer (score -1):

### On Mac Catalina

move mat.app into mac ~/Application, then use it directly