# Eclipse: No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/

Tags: java, eclipse

I opened Eclipse:

[image: Open Eclipse]

I got this Error:

[image: Eclipse Error]

My OS:

[image: Mac OS]

**Text:**

A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse.

No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin

Comment: Your installed Java version is `jdk1.8.0_131`, not `jdk1.8.0_121`.

Comment: How do I fix it so that Eclipse looks for jdk1.8.0_131?

Comment: How did you trigger this message?

Comment: I opened Eclipse.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with mac, but perhaps the environment path, or some other environment variable could have the old version such as JAVA_HOME? You may be able to set it by the java control panel: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_controlpanel.xml

Comment: @PaulT. The screenshot shows JAVA_HOME being echoed

Comment: You may have to edit eclipse.ini https://wiki.eclipse.org/Updating_eclipse.ini_on_MacOS

Comment: You could also upgrade and download Eclipse 4.7

Comment: @cricket_007: ...oh I see, just below the dialog, missed that.

Answer (score 5):

Change "jdk1.8.0_121" to "jdk1.8.0_131" in eclipse.ini

[image: eclipse.ini]

Comment: If you cannot find your eclipse.ini on macbook, try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454889/eclipse-ini-file-not-present-on-mac/28063619#28063619

Comment: I had to use something besides TextEdit to actually edit it (when the package had to be extracted ) (I used textmate)

Answer (score 3):

In something version of eclipse the path for eclipse.ini: `/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini`

put this:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/VERSION.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/
```

Answer (score 2):

When you encounter this error, most probably you or system has updated the Java and the path for the Java virtual machine has changed. Updating the VM path as other answers work but you will have to repeat the same exercise again when Java version updates again. Following is the solution I use to get out of this cycle.

1. Open eclipse package.
   [Open package contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10kvO.png)
2. Open eclipse.ini file in /Content/Eclipse folder
3. Open terminal and type `ls -l /usr/bin/java`
4. Replace `-vm` parameter with the symlink from the terminal. It would most probably be `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe tweaking the Java path (in my case it was the Java version) in /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/info.plist solves the problem.