# Cannot Modify eclipse.ini file on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos

I had a hard time finding the eclipse.ini file ([finally got it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454889/eclipse-ini-file-not-present-on-mac)), but now I can't seem to modify the contents.

On clicking unlock, it says that it's on a read-only volume and cannot be modified.

It gives me the option to duplicate, which I take and then create a new, modified version of the file, but I cannot save it in the original location nor can I paste it in the folder where the current eclipse.ini is.

What should I do?

Comment: Why do you think you need to change it?

Comment: @greg-449 I need to make company-specific changes

Comment: The 'Finder' 'Get Info' dialog will show you the file permissions in the 'Sharing and Permissions' section - you can change the file there to allow you to write it.

Comment: You're not running Eclipse from the downloaded `.dmg` file and expecting to modify the .ini, are you?

Comment: @greg-449 Under the words "Sharing and Permissions", it says  "You can only read". However, next to my name in the list of names, the privilege listed is "Read and Write". What does this mean?

Comment: @nitind I am. What should I do instead in order to modify the file?

Comment: You are supposed to copy Eclipse from the .dmg file to somewhere on your disk - /Applications or your home folder. .dmg images are read only and intended only to be copied. The normal .dmg has a link to 'Applications' so you can just drag 'Eclipse' on to the link to copy it to /Applications.

Comment: @greg-449 That worked, thanks! Feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you missed a step in the installation. If you are installing Eclipse from a .dmg file you must copy the Eclipse app to somewhere on your disk. The .dmg file contains a link to 'Applications', dragging Eclipse on to the link will copy it to the /Applications folder.

Once you have copied the file you can eject the .dmg file and it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

drag and add eclipse into Applications.
Then you will be able to edit the ini file