# Change font size in the project explorer view in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-kepler

I tried to change the font size in the dialog of the views increasing all the font settings in preferences->general->appearance->color and fonts, but it was completely useless.

Does anyone know how can I increase the font size in the view boxes in eclipse? (on a mac the text is very small)

I need to change the font size for example in the project explorer, outline etc..

Comment: have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922305/how-can-i-change-font-size-in-eclipse-for-java-text-editors)   ?

Comment: have you tried closing and opening eclipse?

Comment: yes, the font size in the dialog project explorer and outline is still the same, while all the other fonts are bigger

Comment: you mean this? http://i.imgur.com/98d6htR.png

Comment: I mean the project explorer font size http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-27.htm and any other view

Comment: I've found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124629/how-can-i-configure-the-font-size-for-the-tree-item-in-the-package-explorer-in-e)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35413/discussion-between-q99-and-daniele)