# Problems with 64bit Eclipse UI in Windows 8

Tags: eclipse, windows-8, 64-bit

All of the buttons for run, debug, new class, etc. are incredibly small and almost unreadable. I'm just wondering if there's a way I can get them to be larger. I'm new to eclipse and java and don't have much knowledge on the program or its settings.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically controlled by your host OS settings.  I don't have Windows 8, however on all other OS'es I've had to change the default system font to be larger to effect those used in the Eclipse UI.

Also there are some editor preferences in Eclipse itself that can modify some of these font sizes, however it's usually only the editor font, not the font used on controls.

edit:
I actually found a way to do this which is somewhat of an hack that's sort of detailed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19675350/663367

1. Install the Eclipse 4 CSS Editor plug-in http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-4-tools-lightweight-css-editor
2. Go to the Preferences in Window > Preferences > General > Appearances, you should see a Theme selector, and then a big text area with some CSS-like annotations.  By editing the CSS directly, you can increase the font size of pretty much everything, but Table Headers (my sole pet-peeve).

Comment: Is there a way to change the OS font settings for specific programs?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything like this for Windows 8. Other versions of Windows could use Tweak UI.  For Mac OS, there is [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) which we have used to some success for projector demos of our Eclipse RCP product.  FWIW: The standard toolbar icon sizes for Eclipse are 12x12 pixels - so even if you could make them bigger, it won't make them any more legible.