# Eclipse look&feel configuration in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, gtk, swt

I've got problem with look of freshly installed Eclipse in my Ubuntu 10.04. The toolbars and tabs are just too wide, there's lot of empty space above and below text or images on them, so I wish to make them narrower.

[image: How it looks]

Fast look in google didn't give the answer how to configure it, so I hope someone has dealt with it. This is same with any GTK theme so I suppose there's something to do with SWT configuration. Thanks in advance for any help.

P.S. There were [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743647/gigantic-tabs-in-eclipse-on-ubuntu) some time ago which ended up with advice to use Clearlooks Compact GTK theme, but I don't think it's good solution for this problem. I'm just ok with Ambiance theme and hope there's a way to make SWT applications look good without switching to another theme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a .gtkrc-2.0 file in your home directory.  I'm not on my linux machine currently so I can't paste mine, but [this guy](http://lj4newbies.blogspot.com/2008/02/make-your-eclipse-look-better-on-ubuntu.html) posted his for Ubuntu.  Googling for `eclipse` and `.gtkrc` should find you more.

Comment: Thanks, it seems the right thing I didn't manage to google up.

Answer (score 0):

Juno messes with the tabs as well.  This resource is good awesome! http://blog.nanthrax.net/2012/07/change-tab-font-in-eclipse-juno/