# Very large tabs in Eclipse panes on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, user-interface, gtk

My question is very similar to Stack Overflow question *[Gigantic Tabs in Eclipse on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743647)*.

I have tried the solutions presented, but they appear to be old. I have found [a solution](http://blog.sarathonline.com/2008/10/solved-eclipse-looks-good-in-ubuntu-now.html) that nicely handles the toolbar and menus, but not a solution that reduces the size and padding of the disproportionately large tabs (and label) within the panes (see the tab "Package Explorer" in the screen below).

I am happy with the way my OS-wide GTK theme is customized and don't want to change that. Is there a quick fix to reduce the tab sizes of the panes in Eclipse?

I'm using Eclipse for Mobile Developers (Juno) on Ubuntu 12.04.  I'll also mention that I really like the way Eclipse appears out of the box in Windows 7, so something similar to that would be ideal.

Here are the eclipse specific GTK styles I'm using:

```
style "eclin" {
    GtkButton::default_border={1,1,1,1}
    GtkButton::default_outside_border={1,1,1,1}
    GtkButtonBox::child_min_width=0
    GtkButtonBox::child_min_heigth=0
    GtkButtonBox::child_internal_pad_x=0
    GtkButtonBox::child_internal_pad_y=0
    GtkMenu::vertical-padding=1
    GtkMenuBar::internal_padding=1
    GtkMenuItem::horizontal_padding=4
    GtkToolbar::internal-padding=1
    GtkToolbar::space-size=1
    GtkOptionMenu::indicator_size=0
    GtkOptionMenu::indicator_spacing=0
    GtkPaned::handle_size=4
    GtkRange::trough_border=0
    GtkRange::stepper_spacing=0
    GtkScale::value_spacing=0
    GtkScrolledWindow::scrollbar_spacing=0
    GtkExpander::expander_size=10
    GtkExpander::expander_spacing=0
    GtkTreeView::vertical-separator=0
    GtkTreeView::horizontal-separator=0
    GtkTreeView::expander-size=12
    GtkTreeView::fixed-height-mode=TRUE
    GtkWidget::focus_padding=0
    font_name="Liberation Sans,Sans Regular 8"
}

class "GtkWidget" style "eclin"
    style "eclin2" {
    xthickness=1
    ythickness=1
}

class "GtkButton" style "eclin2"
class "GtkToolbar" style "eclin2"
class "GtkPaned" style "eclin2"
```

Here is a screenshot of what my IDE looks like with the huge tabs:

[image: Eclipse Juno IDE with tabs too big]

Comment: @eicto, you should make this a full answer, and mention that you have to select GTK as the window manager.

Comment: At least since eclipse Mars there is a dedicated font setting for this: Go to Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> View and Editor Folders -> Part title font

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can edit Eclipse's CSS instead of messing with the GTK theme.

In your Eclipse directory find the file `plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.*/css/e4_default_gtk.css` (there's an `*` in there, because I guess that the version may change in the future or may be different already). In this file there's a CSS class:

```
.MPartStack {
    font-size: 11;
    swt-simple: false;
    swt-mru-visible: false;
}
```

And you have two possible solutions:

1. change `font-size` to something smaller
2. just comment out or remove `font-size` from this class (works well for me)

And that should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you!  +1 for conciseness too :).  After knowing what to search for, I was able to find the following documentation for anyone else with a similar problem: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/CSS

Comment: In 4.2, there is a gui option under general -> appearance to use GTK theme instead of classic.

Comment: @Ajax: You are right, and I had to do this to use the custom gtk theme I posted, however the question (and solution) only addresses the tabs which isn't handled by the theme.

Comment: No worries.  Just adding to the knowledge base.

The GTK theme in 4.2 actually seems to make eclipse almost unusably slow, but for the purpose of OS integration, it's handy to know.

Comment: I changed the `font-size` to `9` and I can see the font size become smaller after a restart, but the tab height remained the same. I changed the `swt-tab-height` and `padding` to all `0px` and yet there was no difference. Is there another setting to change?

Comment: Do you know how to do that in fedora eclipse 3.4.2? yeah its old but cant do anything about it

Comment: @haridsv - Did you find a solution to the tab issue?  I'm also not seeing smaller tabs, only smaller fonts in an huge tab.

Comment: @technocrat I don't think so, I will have to check if I did something or if I just got used to it.

Comment: @technocrat I just checked my eclipse setup, and my tab height feels normal. Since the time I upgraded to Juno, I remember only changing the `font-size`, so I am pretty sure I did nothing in this regard. My guess is that something got fixed now in the platform, so if you are not using Juno or a newer release, you could just try upgrading.

Comment: @haridsv Hrm, yea I'm not sure then.  I'm using Kepler.

Comment: OMG it looks so beautiful now I wanna cry. Was bugging the living crap out of me!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Only makes the fonts smaller.

Comment: To Eclipse 4.5 (mars) the path is: <eclipse-home>/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.1.0.v20150511-0913/css

Comment: For mars, using the new installer, i found the file in my home directory: ~/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.1.0.v20150511-0913/css

Comment: For eclipse mars this solution is not enough -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/32229790/1938607

Answer (score 61):

Style of tabs can be changed in Eclipse 4.2 by editing CSS. You can change styles directly in Eclipse Preferences window after installing the E4 CSS editor plug-in.

Go to menu Help > Install new software, then install `E4 CSS editor (Incubation)` plug-in using Eclipse 4 update site (add this link: http://download.eclipse.org/e4/updates/0.12).

After restart, go to Window > Preferences, General > Appearance and now you can edit styles here for any selected theme.

I am using this style for tabs:

```
.MPartStack {
  font-size: 9;
  font-family: Liberation Sans;
  swt-tab-renderer: null;
  swt-tab-height: 22px;
  swt-selected-tabs-background: #FFFFFF #ECE9D8 100%;
  swt-simple: false;
  swt-mru-visible: false;
}
```

You can specify tabs height using the `swt-tab-height` option. It's value sets tab height ignoring the font size.

Comment: Setting `swt-tab-height` is more useful than changing the `font-size` only, thanks, @MrSmith42 every wasted pixel counts unless it is a 4K display :)

Comment: Eclipse Kepler doesn't like parsing comments in the css.  Also used the last recommendation here: http://techtavern.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/smaller-font-sizes-for-eclipse-on-linux/  (Overwriting the theme) to make my package explorer font size smaller.  I also referenced here: https://gist.github.com/andrioli/3825078 for smaller toolbars.  All three of these provided a great minimalist approach for eclipse.

Comment: watch out, you can minimize swt-tab-height so that aditional tab commands/functions wont show.

Comment: Where is this __CSS editor__ now (summer of 2014)? Cannot find it in any repo or the market.

Comment: @Redsandro, you just should edit the same file as in accepted answer. For me it was /usr/share/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.0.0.v20140604-1608/css/e4_default_gtk.css. I've just tested it on new Eclipse Luna, still works fine ;)

Comment: On eclipse Neon, I was able to find the plugin using update site:   [e4 v0.16 updates](http://download.eclipse.org/e4/updates/0.16)
  
The plugin to look for is "E4 CSS editor (Incubation)".
  
Once installed, I was able to edit the Dark theme as follows:
  
`.MPartStack, .MPart {
    font-family: '#org-eclipse-ui-workbench-TAB_TEXT_FONT';
    font-size: 8;
    swt-tab-height: 22px;
}`

Answer (score 13):

I also wanted to reduce especially the horizontal space in order to fit more tabs, as Eclipse lacks multi-row tabs.

These instructions will go for any platform (not limited to e.g. Ubuntu/GTK).

What I did was:

- Reduced the font size
- Changed font to something horizontal-compact
- Removed the X (close tab) button

...yielding the following result on my system (Win 7):

[image: Screenshot with modified tabs]

...and this is how it's done:

1. Check what CSS layout you're using: Preferences->General->Appearance-> check value of 'Theme:' listbox
2. Open the corresponding file in `<eclipse folder>\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_<your version>\css`, e.g. `e4_default_win7.css`
3. Modify `.MPartStack` entries to set font size and font, e.g.:

   ```
   .MPartStack {
       font-size: 8;
       font-family: 'Arial Narrow';
       swt-simple: true;
       swt-mru-visible: false;
   }
   ```
4. Add the following entry to remove the X (close icon):

   ```
   CTabItem {
       swt-show-close: false !important;   
   }
   ```

That's it!

Comment: Nice on the close X removal to save space! +1

Answer (score 8):

Eclipse is now (4.5 Mars) defaulting to GTK3 on Linux. For 4.6 a fix seems to be alredy merged.

Changing `SWT_GTK3` environment variable works for Eclipse Mars:

```
$ export SWT_GTK3=0
```

or set that variable inline with running eclipse

```
$ SWT_GTK3=0 /path/to/eclipse/eclipse
```

To kill it dead just drop this in the root as eclipse.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
SWT_GTK3=0 exec env "${0%.sh}"
```

Comment: To force **Eclipse Mars** to use GTK 2, instead of exporting `SWT_GTK3=0`, you could also start up Eclipse with `{install_path}/eclipse --launcher.GTK_version 2`. To see the version, in Eclipse go to **Help>About Eclipse>Installation Details>Configuration** Tab, and look for `org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.version`.

Comment: This solution also solves the issue where the buttons are very large (along with the tool bars)  This works with the newest (as of Oct 2016) version of Eclipse, Oxygen

Comment: @fr13d, THANKS, setting that switch worked for me. And it is a lot easier than creating separate config files and other headache...

Answer (score 1):

You may try the theme from https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes.

After install this theme, apply it by choosing the theme in Window > Preferences > General > Appearence > Jeeeyul's themes.

And to solve the large tab problem, please refer to https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes/wiki/Linux-Huge-Toolbar-Problem.

It's easy and beatiful. Enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to select:

```
System settings > Universal access > Text size as small.
```

Comment: System settings - where ?

Comment: Ah I am using kde, I was looking in the eclipse ui.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit all small details about tab size here:

[image]