# How can I change vertical spacing in Gtk2 menu items in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gtk, gtk2

I'm trying to make Eclipse UI more compact and already have successfully tweaked it using these instructions:

- [Can I make Eclipse on Ubuntu look more compact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684289/can-i-make-eclipse-on-ubuntu-look-more-compact/13687387#13687387)
- https://gist.github.com/andrioli/3825078

The only remaining thing I want to improve is reducing vertical spacing between menu items as on this picture:

[image: Eclipse menu items].

I looked through GtkMenuItem style properties, but can't find any setting for that. GtkMenu::vertical-padding also doesn't seem to be right one.

Is there any Gtk2 widget property that I can modify to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of settings in your theme's `gtkrc` file that you can modify to make the menu items more compact:

1. To reduce the width and height of the menu items, you can assign a smaller value to the `xthickness` and `ythickness` properties respectively (horizontal and vertical padding respectively between the text and border of a widget). e.g.

   ```
   style "menu_item" {
       xthickness = 1
       ythickness = 1
   }
   ```

   The above code snippet assumes your `GtkMenuItem` widget uses a style called `menu_item` in your theme's `gtkrc` file. i.e.

   ```
   widget_class "*<GtkMenuItem>*" style "menu_item"
   ```
2. The height of the separator menu item (line separating menu items) can be reduced by assigning a smaller value to the `GtkWidget::separator-height` property. e.g.

   ```
   style "separator_menu_item" {
       xthickness = 1
       ythickness = 1

       GtkSeparatorMenuItem::horizontal-padding = 0
       GtkWidget::wide-separators = 1
       GtkWidget::separator-width = 1
       GtkWidget::separator-height = 1
   }
   ```

   Again, the above code snippet assumes your `GtkSeparatorMenuItem` widget uses a style called `separator_menu_item` in your theme's `gtkrc` file. i.e.

   ```
   widget_class "*<GtkSeparatorMenuItem>*" style "separator_menu_item"
   ```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly!